# Solving Differential Algebraic Equations as BVP

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a set of DAEs.

\begin{equation}  
-4 \nu (\lambda(s))^{(-1 - 4 \nu)} \theta'(s) \lambda'(s) + (\lambda(s))^{(-4 \nu)} \theta''(s) = -\alpha_y \cos\theta(s) + \alpha_x \sin\theta(s)   
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
(\lambda(s))^{(-2 \nu)} \log(\lambda(s)) = f_s (\alpha_x \cos\theta(s) + \alpha_y \sin\theta(s)) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\theta(0) = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\theta'(1) = \beta
\end{equation}

where $\lambda$ and $\theta$ are two variables, varying over the range $s \in [0,1]$. $\alpha_x, \alpha_y, \beta, f_s, \nu$ are constants.
When I try to solve them numerically using NDSolve, Mathematica gives me an error saying DAEs must be  given as IVPs.

The code I use is given below

```
i[s] = (lambda[s])^(-4 nu)
i'[s] = D[i[s],s]
Eqn1 = theta''[s] i[s] + theta'[s] i'[s] == alphax Sin[theta[s]] - alphay Cos[theta[s]]
Eqn2 = (lambda[s])^(-2 nu) Log[lambda[s]] == fs*(alphax Cos[theta[s]] + alphay Sin[theta[s]])
BC1 = theta[0] == 0
BC2 = theta'[1] == beta

param = {alphax->0.1, alphay->0.1, beta->0.1, nu->0.3, fs->10^-6}
thetaSol = NDSolve[{Eqn1,Eqn2,BC1,BC2}/.param,{theta,lambda},{s,0,1}]
```

If I can solve the second equation to obtain $\lambda(s)$ as a function of $\theta(s)$, then I can eliminate the second equation and solve it as a second order ODE in $\theta(s)$. However, I believe this sort of equation has a solution using the Lambert W function.

Can I use Mathematica to solve this system of equations?

Comment: Hi ! Please provide any relevant code, so someone can start diggin' right away, not wasting time trying to type in the equations :)

Comment: I have added the code I am currently using. Thanks!

Comment: The numerical values of the parameters $alpha_x, alpha_y$ etc are just as an example for using NDSolve. I need to able to solve the equations for other values too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NDSolve` wants a IVP, why not give it one?:

```
bc3 = theta'[0] == slope;
thetaSol = 
 ParametricNDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, BC1, bc3} /. param, {theta, lambda}, {s, 0, 1}, slope];
```

Then what we need to do is just looking for a proper `slope` that satisfies `BC2`, which is usually a task for `FindRoot`, let's have a look at the *`slope` - `theta'[1]`* relation as insurance:

```
Plot[First@BC2 /. theta -> theta[slope] /. thetaSol /. param // Evaluate, {slope, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

OK, `theta'[1] == 0.1` is near `0`, so:

```
slopeneeded= FindRoot[BC2 /. theta->theta[slope] /. thetaSol /. param//Evaluate, {slope, 0}]
```

> ```
> {slope -> 0.191621}
> ```

```
{θ[s_], λ[s_]} = {theta[slope][s], lambda[slope][s]} /. thetaSol /. slopeneeded;

Plot[{θ[s], λ[s]}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to get the result you get when you solve for `slopeneeded`. Can you please verify it?

Comment: @VenkatKV Of course: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wPNna.jpg  What do you mean by "ot able to get the result"? The result is wrong, or it doesn't give any result, or something else? BTW, `ParametricNDSolve` is a v9 function.

Comment: This is the code I am using. Similar to yours. You can see the results I get. http://imgur.com/ohwXcUN
I notice the you are using `theta'[0]=slope` instead of `==` in your code. Maybe that's an error?

Comment: @VenkatKV No, it's just the `StandardForm` of `==`. (Notice its length. ) Which version of _Mathematica_ are you using? What's your platform? I'm using v9.0.1, vista 32bit. You can try narrowing down the scope of `FindRoot`, for example `{slope, 0.1, 0.3}` etc.

Comment: I am using version 10.0.1. 
Providing the range for `FindRoot` seems to have done the trick for the calculation of `slope`. I will try doing the calculations for a large range of loads to see if the method works. Thanks!

Comment: @VenkatKV You can also consider using [`RootSearch`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/). BTW, you can [click the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to accept it if satisfied with an answer.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With your set of parameters your second equation looks as follows:

```
param = {alphax -> 0.1, alphay -> 0.1, beta -> 0.1, nu -> 0.3, fs -> 10^-6};
eqn2 = (lambda[s])^(-2 nu) Log[lambda[s]] == 
    fs*(alphax Cos[theta[s]] + alphay Sin[theta[s]]) /. 
   param /. {lambda[s] -> λ, theta[s] -> θ}

(*  Log[λ]/λ^0.6 == (0.1 Cos[θ] + 0.1 Sin[θ])/1000000   *)
```

One can see that the right-hand side has the factor of 10^-7. In principle I would say that with a perfect accuracy you can assume the right-hand side to be equal to zero. Then `lambda=1`, and you can easily solve your equation Nr. 1:

```
 thetaSol = 
 NDSolve[{theta''[s] == -0.1` Cos[theta[s]] + 
      0.1` Sin[theta[s]], theta[0] == 0, theta'[0] == 0.1}, 
   theta[s], {s, 0, 1}][[1, 1]]

Plot[Evaluate[theta[s] /. thetaSol], {s, 0, 1}]
```

This should return this plot:
[image]

If, however, for some reason (that I am unable to imagine) you need these tiny differences, then you may process as follows. This

```
lst = Table[{θ, 
 FindRoot[
   Log[λ]/λ^0.6` == (
    0.1` Cos[θ] + 0.1` Sin[θ])/1000000, {λ, 
    0.9}, WorkingPrecision -> 8][[1, 2]]}, {θ, 0, 2 π, 
 0.1}] // Quiet;
```

gives you a table of solutions with the structure `{theta, lambda}`. This fits it:

```
lst1 = lst /. {θ_, λ_} -> {θ, λ - 1};
ft = Fit[lst1, {1, Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, θ]
Show[{
  lstPl = ListPlot[lst1],
  Plot[ft, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
  }]
```

This is the returned visualization of the fitting quality:
[image]

Note that I fit `{theta, lambda-1}` instead of the initial list. Otherwise the differences would be difficult to recognize. Now your result for `lambda[theta]`is `1+ft`. That is

```
λ =  1.000000000 + -1.8133184287449915`*^-8 + 
     1.0016280409439516`*^-7 Cos[θ] + 9.982597207356538`*^-8 Sin[θ]
```

Have fun!

Comment: I think you may be interested in [this site](http://steampiano.net/msc/) :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the numerical values of $alphax, alphay$ etc are just as an example. I need to be able to solve the equations for a much larger range of values, in which case $lambda$ is not equal to $1$.
However, the second part of your reply on how to numerically obtain $lambda(theta)$ is very useful.