# Split Boundary Value Problems with Algebraic Equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

Is it possible at all to solve with NDSolve (or other built in function) a **split boundary value** problem with algebraic equations?

Please look at the following example:

```
s = NDSolve[
   {
    x'[t] == y[t] + x[t] y[t] + z[t],
    z'[t] == 2*y[t],
    2 x[t] + y[t] - z[t] == 1,
    x[0] == 0,
    z[0] == 0}
   , {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

This example solves well, and outputs Interpolation Functions.

I compute the final value of variable `z`:

```
In[50]:= z[1] /. s
Out[51]:= {0.694658}
```

When I try the same example with split conditions:

```
s1 = NDSolve[
   {
    x'[t] == y[t] + x[t] y[t] + z[t],
    z'[t] == 2*y[t],
    2 x[t] + y[t] - z[t] == 1,
    x[0] == 0,
    z[1] == 0.694658}
   , {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

I get the following error:

```
NDSolve::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems.
```

I am trying to solve a complex problem with this structure, is there any way to tackle it in mathematica?

Edit: Unlike this Minimum Working Example, in the original problem I am trying to solve the variable y cannot be eliminated from the system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, `NDSolve` cannot solve this equation as written.  However, it is easy enough to eliminate `y` from the system.

```
{x'[t] == y[t] + x[t] y[t] + z[t], z'[t] == 2*y[t]} /. y[t] -> 1 + z[t] - 2 x[t]
```

and then solve and plot

```
s1 = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == 1 - 2 x[t] + 2 z[t] + x[t] (1 - 2 x[t] + z[t]), 
    Derivative[1][z][t] == 2 (1 - 2 x[t] + z[t]), x[0] == 0, 
    z[1] == 0.694658}, {x, z}, {t, 0, 1}]    
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], 1 + z[t] - 2 x[t], z[t]} /. s1], {t, 0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "x, y, z"}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

A similar problem is [63824](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63873/1063).  Its approach can be applied as follows.

```
s3 = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t] + x[t] y[t] + z[t], z'[t] == 2*y[t], 
    2 x[t] + y[t] - z[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, z[0] == a}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1}, {a}];
f[w_?NumericQ] := z[w][1] /. s3
w0 = w /. FindRoot[f[w] == 0.694658, {w, .1}]
(* -2.47361*10^-6 *)
Plot[Evaluate[{x[w0][t], y[w0][t], z[w0][t]} /. s3], {t, 0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "x, y, z"}]
```

which gives the same plot shown above.  Note that the value of `w0` is zero to roundoff.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I am trying to solve a more complex system where the equivalent of y cannot be eliminated.

Comment: @Antonio  You may find the discussion [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html) useful.

Comment: @Antonio  In  response to your comment, I was able to find an alternative approach that does not involve eliminating `y` from the equations.  Basically, it is the standard shooting method.  Why `NDSolve` does not use it in this case is unclear to me.